# Get Nlog values from appsettings.json

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, nlog

My goal is to inject values from the appsettings.json into nlog.config for an ASP.NET Core application. I am using NLog.Web.AspNetCore 4.8.3, NLog 4.6.5, NLog.config 4.6.5, and Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions 2.0.0.

I wasn't able to get this working. I was under the impression that **${configsetting:name=ConnectionStrings.ApplicationDatabase}** would be replaced with the **ConnectionStrings.ApplicationDatabase** value inside of my appsettings.json file but this does not work. The nlog.config variable value is unchanged and throws an error when I run my application because that is an invalid connection string.

**Snippet of nlog.config**

```
<!-- Using logDirectory variable to set path to src/logs folder in allfile and ownFile-web targets below -->
  <variable name="logDirectory" value="${basedir}/../../../logs/${shortdate}/internal-nlog.log" />
  <variable name="logDatabase" value="${configsetting:name=ConnectionStrings.ApplicationDatabase}"/>
  <variable name="logDatabaseUser" value="${configsetting:name=DatabaseCredentials.User}"/>
  <variable name="logDatabasePassword" value="${configsetting:name=DatabaseCredentials.Password}"/>-->
  <variable name="logConnectionString" value="mongodb://${logDatabaseUser}:${logDatabasePassword}@${logDatabase}/myApplicationDB?authSource=admin"/>

  <!-- Load the ASP.NET Core plugin -->
  <extensions>
    <add assembly="NLog.Web.AspNetCore" />
    <add assembly="NLog.Mongo" />
  </extensions>

  <!-- the targets to write to -->
  <targets>
    <!-- write logs to file -->
    <target xsi:type="File" name="allfile" fileName="${logDirectory}"
            layout="${longdate}|${event-properties:item=EventId.Id}|${logger}|${uppercase:${level}}|${message} ${exception}" />

    <!-- another file log, only own logs. Uses some ASP.NET core renderers -->
    <target xsi:type="File" name="ownFile-web" fileName="${logDirectory}"
            layout="${longdate}|${event-properties:item=EventId.Id}|${logger}|${uppercase:${level}}|  ${message} ${exception}|url: ${aspnet-request-url}|action: ${aspnet-mvc-action}" />

    <target xsi:type="Mongo" name="error-mongo"
            connectionString="${logConnectionString}"
            collectionName="errorLogs">
      <field name="date" layout="${date}" bsonType="DateTime" />
      <field name="level" layout="${level}" />
      <field name="message" layout="${message}" />
      <field name="logger" layout="${logger}" />
      <field name="exception" layout="${exception:format=tostring}" />
      <field name="threadID" layout="${threadid}" bsonType="Int32" />
      <field name="threadName" layout="${threadname}" />
      <field name="processID" layout="${processid}" bsonType="Int32" />
      <field name="processName" layout="${processname:fullName=true}" />
      <field name="userName" layout="${windows-identity}" />
    </target>

<target xsi:type="Mongo" name="event-mongo"
         connectionString="${logConnectionString}"
         collectionName="eventLogs">
      <field name="date" layout="${date}" bsonType="DateTime" />
      <field name="level" layout="${level}" />
      <field name="event" layout="${event-properties:item=EventId.Id}" />
      <field name="message" layout="${message}" />
      <field name="logger" layout="${logger}" />
    </target>
  </targets>
```

**Snippet of appsetting.json**

```
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "ApplicationDatabase": "App-db-server-1.com:27017,App-db-server-2.com:27017,App-db-server-3.com:27017/AccessManagement?ssl=true&replicaSet=myReplicaSet&authSource=admin"
  },
  "DatabaseCredentials": {
    "User": "",
    "Password": ""
  }
}
```

**Snippet of startup.cs**

```
   // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();

            ConfigureNLog(app, loggerFactory);

            /*These settings need to be changed*/
            app.UseCors(
                options => options
                    .AllowAnyOrigin()
                    .AllowAnyMethod()
                    .AllowAnyHeader()
            );

            app.UseAuthentication();
            //Swagger Set Up
            app.UseSwagger();
            app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Authentication API V1");
            });
            app.UseMvc();
        }

        private static void ConfigureNLog(IApplicationBuilder app, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            IConfigurationRoot config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .AddJsonFile(path: "appSettings.json").Build();
            NLog.Extensions.Logging.ConfigSettingLayoutRenderer.DefaultConfiguration = config;
        }
```

**Snippet of Program.cs

```
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            BuildWebHost(args).Run();
        }

        public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args)
        {
            return WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
                {
                    logging.ClearProviders();
                    logging.SetMinimumLevel(Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LogLevel.Trace);
                })
                .UseNLog()
                .Build();
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you read the documentation for NLog ConfigSetting Layout Renderer: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/ConfigSetting-Layout-Renderer Then you can read it will only work out-of-the-box if calling `UseNLog()`. If you are swimming in your own direction then you must assign the `DefaultConfiguration` directly in code.

Comment: Could you provide a link to the nuget-package that includes the assembly `Log.Mongo` or have you misspelled `<add assembly="NLog.Mongo" />` ?

Comment: This was a typo but the results are the same.

Comment: I just tried your variables-setup together with your appsettings.json, and it resolves fine for me. So I guess you have to enable the NLog Internal Logger and see what you are doing wrong: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Internal-Logging

Answer (score 3):

From https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/ConfigSetting-Layout-Renderer

When calling `UseNLog()` from `NLog.Web.AspNetCore` or `NLog.Extensions.Hosting` then it will automatically register hosting environment configuration with `ConfigSettingLayoutRenderer`.

To manual register the Microsoft Extension `IConfiguration` with `${configsetting}`:

```cs
IConfigurationRoot config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .AddJsonFile(path: "AppSettings.json").Build();
NLog.Extensions.Logging.ConfigSettingLayoutRenderer.DefaultConfiguration = config;
```

Update, demo case here https://github.com/304NotModified/NLog-Demo-cases/tree/master/AspNetCore2WithConfigSetting

Comment: So I added the Program.cs file in my post above, still doesnt work. Do I need to do anything else for NLog to understand it needs to parse and replace the setting in the nlog.config file. It tries the log to the Mongo target configured but the connection string is still "mongodb://${logDatabaseUser}:${logDatabasePassword}@${logDatabase}/myApplicationDB?authSource=admin".

Comment: just add these lines in `ConfigureNLog`

Comment: So I modified that, but the error I still get is that the connection string "${logConnectionString}" is not valid. Is there a working example that shows we can inject a value from the appsettings.json directly into a variable? I've tried this a number of ways and I can't seem to get this going. My app is .NET Core 2.0.

Comment: @user95488 created demo here. https://github.com/304NotModified/NLog-Demo-cases/tree/master/AspNetCore2WithConfigSetting

works on my machine. Be sure to update the correct nlog.config (build will copy it to the bin)